# Making Text box not editable

Tags: asp.net

**work on C# asp.net vs 05.** I have a  requirment, **I have to fill text box with some data on gridview , which is coming from database and make it read-only**

After that user can not enter any text on gridview template field. If I set textbox `Enabled=false`, then i lose text color, but i want to show text color. Just textbox to not be editable. I just want users to not be able to write anything in my textbox.

Comment: You should remove all your "....", it just make your question harder to read.

Answer (score 10):

Isn't there a readonly property for the text box.

If then you can use

ReadOnly="true"

for the text box.

If you can ***use a label*** then I would prefer that one.

For wrapping contents inside a label you can use

[word-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap)

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Inside the properties choose your column field and in the properties.

Under **Styles** section

You can give a **CssClass** to the column.

If you specify CssClass as 'TextStyle'

the css looks like this

```
.TextStyle
{
    color: #a9a9a9
}
```

In the color attribute give either the color name like 'red' or the hexcode like '#000000' for the text.

Comment: waht to write on css...i want this syntax

Comment: There's nothing to write in CSS using this suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Enabled="false"

Comment: This would be the preferred method for a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your CSS for the TextBox in the row created event of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CSS to make a label look like a textbox.

Comment: i also want to use the label but ....label can not warp...so column with can not control.....how to warp label?

Comment: I think you mean wrap, as opposed to warp?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick proof of concept I just knocked up.

```
<head runat="server">
    <style>
    .readTest 
    {
        border: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="Do something" ReadOnly="true" 
       ID="txtOne" CssClass="readTest"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Personally I would use a label, though you could write a custom control that renders a textbox or a label, depending on the state your app is in.

Answer (score 0):

Why does everyone insist on using an asp:label for this sort of thing? Just because it renders a `<span>` if you don't supply an AssociatedControlId?

You should look at using an [asp:Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) or possibly an [asp:Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.Literal.aspx) or [asp:PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) for this as they will give you greater control over the output, and cleaner markup.

Panel would be better, as this will render the contents in a `<div>` rather than the PlaceHolder or Literal which won't add any extra markup.

The content you are putting in here is a semantic division, and so should really be marked up as such, and by default, `<div>`s are treated as a block display type, rather than as inline (`<span>`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to write the text directly to the cell using a literal or String() output rather than using a control. It's a bit cleaner and will help minimize the amount of ViewState being written. Either that, or turn off ViewState for those controls being added.