# enable edit box only after selecting the radio button

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-button

I have two radio buttons i.e., call and email. When call is selected then the edit box should get enabled and then user may enter the mobile number.
I've checked these links:
[Enable a text box only when 1 of the radio button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752408/enable-a-text-box-only-when-1-of-the-radio-button-is-clicked)

[Enable text box based on radio button selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131827/enable-text-box-based-on-radio-button-selected)

[Making Text box not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459627/making-text-box-not-editable)

but am not able to achieve this task.

Here is my code:

```
     <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  >

            <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">

             <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/radio0"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="@string/call"/>

             <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/radio1"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/email"
             android:layout_weight="1" />
             </RadioGroup>
             </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mobile"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:inputType="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String mobile;

RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit.setEnabled(false);
    edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    edit.setFocusable(false);

    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio0:   
                op1="call";
                actv(); 
                break;

            case R.id.radio1:
                op1="email";
                break;

            }   

        }
    });

    public void actv() {
    edit.setEnabled(true);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        edit.setFocusable(true);
    }
```

Comment: Can you define not working? what happens with this code?

Comment: Where are you defining rg1 in java??

Comment: @Zoya RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1); included this before onCreate method 

@ MagicalPhoenixϡ Not working means the screen is not displayed..this is my 1st screen so as soon as i start the app it says "the application has stopped unexpectedly..please try again.."

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: sorry @zoya...i am downloading .apk and testing..log cat is not generated that's why am not able to trace out the error

Comment: from where you are downloading the apk?? how can you generate apk without generating logcat?

Comment: I've written the code->checked for errors->no errors->export as signed...thats it..apk generated..but no logcat will get generated in this case i guess,,because my logcat window is empty

Comment: Add 

    `RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

after your `setContentView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides correcting your member initialization (as suggested in each of the previous answers), you need to fix your layout (it is closed too early, resulting in an invalid xml).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/call" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/email" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="@string/mobile"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also decide which way you'd like to prevent the user from typing into the edittext (disable / hide / input type tweaks).

And last but not least, put all of these together in a clean manner:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private String op1;

    private RadioGroup rg1;
    private EditText edit;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        actv(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        switch (checkedId)
        {
            case R.id.radio0:
                op1 = "call";
                actv(true);
                break;

            case R.id.radio1:
                op1 = "email";
                actv(false);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void actv(final boolean active)
    {
        edit.setEnabled(active);
        if (active)
        {
            edit.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rekaszeru...1 doubt..can we include php code in the java pages of android(if yes,then how)..see,I want to retrieve data stored in my localhost database using WHERE clause(like SELECT * FROM information WHERE mobile='9123456789'..)and fill the details in next form(something like autofill but I dont want ant suggestion in edit text)..how do i achieve it..shall I inlude/import a php file

Answer (score 0):

> @Zoya RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
>   included this before onCreate method @ MagicalPhoenixϡ Not working
>   means the screen is not displayed..this is my 1st screen so as soon as
>   i start the app it says "the application has stopped
>   unexpectedly..please try again.."

It's giving crash.

**REASON:**

```
RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

You have included these *before* `onCreate` method.

This won't work, obviously.

Add that after your `setContentView` call inside `onCreate` method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

after:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in your onCreate();

Also make sure to set edit.setEditable(false) when radio1 is checked.

Complete Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String mobile;

RadioGroup rg1 = null;
EditText edit = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edit.setEnabled(false);
    edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    edit.setFocusable(false);

    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio0:   
                op1="call";
                enableEdit(true); 
                break;

            case R.id.radio1:
                op1="email";
                enableEdit(false); 
                break;

            }   

        }
    });
    }

    public void enableEdit(boolean state) {
        edit.setEnabled(state);
        edit.setFocusable(state);
        if(state){ edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); } 
        else { edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); }
    }
}
```

Comment: set edit.setEditable(false) when radio1 is checked...shall i add this statement within switch case..
i added 
       1)   edit.setEnabled(false);
       2)   edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
       3)   edit.setFocusable(false);   these 3 lines in onCreate method

Comment: Yes, you can add this to the switch-statement in your OnCheckedStateListener.. Check "complete code". Good luck!

Comment: nope...edit text is not enabled after selecting call ):

Answer (score 0):

This is What you need to do

Change this

```
RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to this

```
RadioGroup rg1 = null;
EditText edit = null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}
```

Thanks :)